# Sorting two arrays that are linked into descending order. One is a string array, one is an int array. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm still relatively new to coding and a recent assignment I had has been stumping me quite a bit.

I have two arrays that are essentially linked to one another. 0 on one side must be 0 on the other, and I need to find the easiest way to sort the one with the numbers into descending order while doing the same to the other side.

```
int main()
{
/// Declare Variables
    int studentNum, j;
    int studentGrade[20];
    string studentName[20];

/// Prompt the user for the number of loops that will be required
    cout << "How many students are in the class? ";
    cin >> studentNum;
    cout << endl;

/// Enter a for loop
    for(int i=0;i<studentNum;i++)
    {
    /// Prompt the user to enter the names of each student in the array, as well as their respective grade.
        cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
        cin >> studentName[i];
        cout << "Enter the student's grade (0-100): ";
        cin >> studentGrade[i];
    }


    cout << endl << endl;


    cout << setw(25) << left << "Student's Name" << setw(25)<< "Test Score" << endl;


///********Sorting block required*********
    

/// Enter another for loop, this time to show the array to the screen
    for (int i=0;i<studentNum;i++)
    {
        cout << setw(25) << studentName[i] << setw(25) << studentGrade[i] << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've looked up as many answers to this question as I can, but haven't been able to find something that would work for me. Does anyone know something I could do here? I have to keep these as two separate arrays. If possible as well, I'd like to try not using sort().

Comment: You want to sort and not use `sort()`?  Then you'll have to make your own sort.

Comment: You want to sort the names and keep the grades in corresponding order to match the names?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need them to match the order the names are in. And yeah I can't use sort(), I'm only asking here because the website for my textbook is down for maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the arrays like this in a double for loop:

```
for(int j=0 ; j<studentNum ; j++)
    for(int i=0 ; i<studentNum-1 ; i++){
        if(studentGrade[i] < studentGrade[i+1]){ //swapping condition
            string temp = studentName[i];
            studentName[i] = studentName[i+1];
            studentName[i+1] = temp;
            int x = studentGrade[i];
            studentGrade[i] = studentGrade[i+1];
            studentGrade[i+1] = x;
        }
    }
```

If the grade of a student in the array is lower than the grade of the student next to him in the array then you could swap them and also swap their names respectively

Comment: Yes! That works, awesome. I appreciate it, the website I use for my textbook is down right now so I really needed some help with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter what sorting algorithm you choose, you just need to go through one of the arrays and whenever you change a cell's index you do it to the same cell index in the other array

for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
     if(arr[i]<arr[i+1]){
          temp=arr[i];
          temp2=arr2[i];
          arr[i]=arr[i+1];
          arr2[i]=arr2[i+1];
          arr[i+1]=temp;
          arr2[i+1]=temp2;
     }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't sort it completely, it changes the order whilst keeping them aligned, but doesn't place the greatest at the top, lowest at the bottom, etc. 

For instance if bob gets a 25, James gets a 30, Alex gets a 78, the array after sorting is

"James 30   Alex 78  Bob 25" instead of "Alex 78   James 30   Bob 25" And I'm so confused regarding this sorting part that I don't know where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the C++ STL conventions, `vector`, `pair` and `sort`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    vector<pair<string, int> > students;

    cin >> n;
    // Input name and grade of all students
    while (n--) {
        string name;
        int grade;
        cin >> name >> grade;
        students.push_back(make_pair(name, grade));
    }
    
    // Sort students based on their grades descending
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(),
        [](const auto & a, const auto & b) -> bool {
            return a.second > b.second;
        });

    // Output students' name and grade
    for (auto & s : students) {
        cout << setw(25) << s.first << setw(25) << s.second << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are not two arrays! If it is a homework, he will get 0 points if he replaces the task by solving a different task! He may aswell build a shuffling-algorithm as answer then.

Comment: Maybe you can create a vector of pair of references instead. Or pass custom iterators to sort that will swap both arrays... Or copy the two arrays into the vector and afterwards copy them out...